# Contact Book Saved Contacts Reference in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios11

How to fetched/get Contacts References from iPhone Contact app for storing in Local Data Storage such as (Core Data) in iOS (IOS >= 10)? Will this possible and apple allow it?
How to fetched the contact information again based on contact reference?
(IOS >= 10)

Comment: I don't know what you are planning/working on, but you can use the Contacts framework to gain readonly access to a user's contacts.  [Contacts Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts)

Comment: i want to get the user saved contacts references from contacts book and store it on local data so that any change in saved contact we get the updated information based on saved reference link 
just like a UIImagePickerController give you file reference of Capture Photo.
@Jacob Boyd